# Validation Controls giving exception when used with GridView on Delete click

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview

How to call javascript function when using validation controls on GridView.

I am trying to call confirmDelete function on delete button of GridViews delete button. 
I dont have a code as of now. But when I was trying it was throwing an exception at javascript

Comment: Are you using <asp:ButtonField /> as delete button?

Comment: @Musa: No I am using ImageButton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code how I use javascript confirm on GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnCommand="btnDelete_Command" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ImageUrl="~/img/delete.png" 
                    OnClientClick="return btnDelete_Click()"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnDelete_Click() {
        return window.confirm('You sure?');
    }
</script>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        gv.DataSource = list;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnDelete_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    // Delete Operation.
}
```

I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: @Musa: This kind of Code I have written. Every thing in the button part is same, Only thing that I added is validation and after adding validation controls of asp.net. My confirm button stopped working. A javascript exception is occuring now again and again.

Comment: Can you write the javascript exception message?

Comment: @Musa: I am getting this error **Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected**

Comment: `<input type="image" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphBody$midbox$gvProcedure$ctl08$btnDelete" id="ctl00_ctl00_cphBody_midbox_gvProcedure_ctl08_btnDelete" src="../images/delete.jpg" alt="Delete" onclick="return ConfirmDelete();" style="border-width:0px;" />` This is my line on which javascript error is occuring. ConfirmDelete function resides in external js file

Comment: May be your page cannot get through the external js file. May be there is a problem with <script src="Scripts/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script> tag inside the <head> tags. You can try it with the scripts inside the page or be sure to add external js file to the page succesfully. Good luck.

Comment: Or ofcourse you can just do: <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" OnCommand="btnDelete_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Id") %>' ImageUrl="~/img/delete.png" OnClientClick="return window.confirm('You Sure?');"/>